# Data is shown in the console but not in the website Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

This is my ngOnInit method:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    
    return this.http.get(this.apiserver.apiUrl + 'negocios/listadoTodos/?negocio=1').subscribe(async (todos:any) => {
        this.detalles = todos;
        console.log(this.detalles);
        
      });
    
}
```

My console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrDKS.png)

My Html:

```
<div class="text-lg font-bold leading-none" *ngFor="let item of detalles">{{item.nombre}} - {{item.sector}}</div>
```

Im trying to use an api that is on my localhost and idk why at the console it is working but not in the frontend html.

Comment: can u show console.log from todos?

Comment: Can you show whole component html and ts code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API might tacking time to load data so when API call get data it will print data in console but before that your HTML render on browser, so you need to use *ngIf before you *ngFor like this.

```
<div *ngIf="detalles.length">    
    <div class="text-lg font-bold leading-none" *ngFor="let item of detalles"> 
         {{item.nombre}} - {{item.sector}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for meeee thank u so much I spend my whole day looking for an answer for this problem

Comment: excellent answer, you saved also my day, ...